# Is it permitted for a woman to kiss another woman on the cheek?

Tags: homosexuality, kissing

I saw a Muslim woman kiss a non-muslim woman on the cheek as a sign of affection. I am not sure if this was a sign of attraction or just to show thanks.
Is this permitted in Islam?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's nothing wrong with a woman kissing another woman or a man kissing another man on the cheek, as a greeting, sign of gratitude, etc.

Comment: When does it become an issue?

Comment: What do you mean? In Muslim cultures, in general, kissing on the cheek is seen as a greeting between friends, family members, etc. It's not sexual.

Comment: So, just kissing on the lips is a crime?

Comment: not sure if it's a "crime", but yes kissing on the lips is reserved for one's spouse (hence, different gender).